# How to load polygon layer with single field as virtual layer?

Tags: qgis, virtual-layer

I have a polygon layer with 3 fields (A, B and C). I want to create a copy and add as a virtual layer so I use CREATE VIRTUAL LAYER option but only want the first field.

So I use the expression `Select A from "polygon layer"`

But it doesnt work. What is wrong with my expression? The fields only contain string values. Do I need to specify geometry column?

This expression works `Select * from "polygon layer` but takes all fields.

Answer (score 4):

You forget the 4th field: geometry.  It is not shown as a column, but it is there. If you do `select * from layer`, then in fact you call `select geometry, A, B, C from layer`.

So, if you want to load a copy of the original with only column 'A', you also have to call the geometry into the expression:

```
select geometry, A from layer
```