# Creating Virtual Layer with only desired fields

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, query, virtual-layer

My question is very similar to [this one](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/296142/how-to-load-polygon-layer-with-single-field-as-virtual-layer). The difference being I want multiple fields where they wanted only a single field.

I'm trying to create a virtual copy of my layer with only the following fields:
`"Acres"`, `"Zoning"`, and `"LinktoSOA"`.

I've tried these queries, but neither worked.

```sql
Select geometry, IN ["Acres", "Zoning", "LinktoSOA"]
from "WilmingtonParcels"
```

```sql
Select geometry, IN {"Acres", "Zoning", "LinktoSOA"}
from "WilmingtonParcels"
```

```sql
Select geometry, IN ("Acres", "Zoning", "LinktoSOA")
from "WilmingtonParcels"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution.

```sql
Select geometry, "Acres", "Zoning", "LinktoSOA"
from "WilmingtonParcels"
```

[image]